# kotlin android studio why doesn't it save?

Tags: android, kotlin

I wrote a simple clicker using a picture and a variable. I want to make sure that when I exit the application and enter it afterwards, my clicks remain the same as when I exited.
I don't understand why it doesn't save the data.

```kotlin
private var value = 0
private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
@SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(layout.activity_main)

    val text = findViewById<TextView>(clicks)
    val btn1 = findViewById<ImageButton>(btn)

    text.text = value.toString()

    btn1.setOnClickListener {
        value++
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("value", MODE_PRIVATE)
        text.text = value.toString()

        val edit = sharedPreferences.edit()
        edit.putInt("value" , value)
        edit.apply()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably saving it just fine, but nowhere are you reading the sharedpreference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You save value just fine but didn't recover it when relaunching the app.

```kotlin
private var value = 0
private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
@SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(layout.activity_main)

    val text = findViewById<TextView>(clicks)
    val btn1 = findViewById<ImageButton>(btn)

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("value", MODE_PRIVATE)
    value = sharedPreferences.getInt("value", 0)

    text.text = value.toString()

    btn1.setOnClickListener {
        value++

        text.text = value.toString()

        val edit = sharedPreferences.edit()
        edit.putInt("value" , value)
        edit.apply()
    }
}
```